# Eureka default zone setting is not picked up when used in application.yaml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

springBootVersion = '2.7.5'

My application is a Eureka Client

Eureka propeties in application.yaml looks like

[image: application.yaml]

I have added restTemplate beans with and without loadbalancer like below

[image: bean config]

The external API I am consuming is registered in a registry which is accessed via credentials, I am loading these credentials from vault during application booting.

Also the external API has a base url, for example https://ABC-V2.

My understanding is when the application starts, this base url is automatically mapped to the eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone. But my API call fails with the exception,

**2023-11-21 21:59:14,556 [main] WARN   o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer - No instances available for ABC-V2**

How to resolve this issue? any alternative I could try to migrate this into spring load balancer?

Comment: What does the eureka console say?

Comment: @spencergibb I don't have access Eureka console as it's maintained by another team.

Comment: That's going to be hard to help without knowing what's in eureka